# Java, make sure that a user doesn't enter numbers in a string

Tags: java, swing, numbers, pattern-matching, joptionpane

I'm trying to create a text based game in Java that I will ask for a user's name and insert it into the game. I'm trying to evaluate with the string that they entered has any number. i.e `09452` or `asdf1234`.

Here is the code that is relative to the problem.

```
String name, choiceSelection;
int choice;
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name!");

//CHECKS IF USER ENTERED LETTERS ONLY
if (Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", name))
{
    throw new NumberFormatException();
} 
else if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", name)) 
{
    if (Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", name))
    {
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out if any number is in the string and if so, throw a `NumberFormatException` so that they know they didn't follow the correct prompt.

What is the best way to make sure the user doesn't enter numbers in the `name` String?

Comment: can you please post the complete code.

Comment: in Swing there are JFormattedTextField or DocumentFilter for plain JTextField

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simpler check:

```
if (!name.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").equals(name)) {
    // name contains digits
}
```

The [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) call removes all digits from the `name`. The `equals` check would succeed only when there are no digits to remove.

Note that throwing `NumberFormatException` in this case would be misleading, because the exception has a very different meaning.

Comment: Thanks for that. It works just fine now. I tend to like to complicate things in my coding.

Comment: I understand but it is easier to work with in my program than multiple try and catches in my coding that would cause me big confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or input verifier to prevent the user from entering numbers in the first place.  It may not be worth losing the JOptionPane simplicity for a throwaway project, but it simplifies things for the end user.

Answer (score 2):

Or, You simply don't let the User to put any numeric value in `textField` .For that you are needed to create Customized `PlainDocument` say `NonNumericDocument` and setting the `Document` of JTextField object as that customized `NonNumericDocument`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

class NonNumericDocument extends PlainDocument 
{
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException 
    {
        if (str == null) 
        {
            return;
        }
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(arr[i]) || !Character.isLetter(arr[i]))//Checking for Numeric value or any special characters
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        super.insertString(offs, new String(str), a);
    }
}
//How to use NonNumericDocument
class  TextFrame extends JFrame
{
    JTextField tf ;
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        tf = new JTextField(30);
        tf.setDocument(new NonNumericDocument());//Set Document here.
        getContentPane().add(tf,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TextFrame tFrame = new TextFrame();
                tFrame.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can use this `NonNumericDocument` with any JTextField in your code without worrying about handling of `non-numeric` characters explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user to only enter letters you can do this:

```
if (name.matches("\\p{Alpha}+")) {
    // name contains only letters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check it is using `parseInt( String s )` method:

```
private boolean isNumber( String s ) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt( s );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return false; // if it is not a number it throws an exception
    }
    return true;
}
```